# Chrome window targeting without common launch relationship

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, frames

I'm doing an application where one window needs to talk to another, even though they didn't originally come from a common page. There seems to be a requirement in Chrome that this is so.

The two windows *are* from the same domain, which I control, but one might be launched from a bookmark and the other from an Excel worksheet.

I've got a demo here:

http://cfpreview12.dmclub.net/Frametest/europe.htm

Go to that URL (with Chrome)
- Launch France
- Launch Germany
- Click on "Go to Paris"
and it works (because France and Germany had a common referrer).

Now copy the URL of the France tab, close the tab, create a new tab 
*manually* and paste back the URL.

When you then flick back to Germany and click on "Go to Paris", a NEW TAB is created, seemingly because Chrome doesn't see the relation between windows that don't have a 
shared heritage.

I have full control over both pages (France and Germany) but in the real 
use, there is no such thing as Europe.

Any ideas on workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use `target` directly; you'll have to do navigations from the JavaScript in each context, sending messages from the scripts in each different window between each other.

OK, so how do we get scripts in different windows (but the same domain) to communication when they don't have a shared reference to a `window`?

1. The old-school way, write values to `document.cookie` and they will be visible to scripts on other windows in the same domain. Requires some annoying protocol overhead in polling for cookie changes, acknowledging receipt/deleting, and encoding long messages (as cookie lengths are limited).
2. The slightly better version of the same thing using `localStorage` instead of cookies where available - avoids polluting the cookie header and increases the length of data that can go in a single message.
3. The modern way - create a [SharedWorker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#shared-workers-introduction) and communicate with it from each window. Unfortunately [limited](http://caniuse.com/sharedworkers) availability at present.

You can of course fall back from (3) to (2) to (1) as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. What a shame there's no way to get a reference to other windows such that one can postMessages to them. I get the impression that Chrome is running a bit of a "Nanny State" ;-)